# Creating a custom Scheduled Job monitor ATG

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, atg, oracle-commerce

I'm currently researching on how I could eventually create a Web App that would be able to monitor Scheduled Jobs that run on a website. It's based on **ATG** and I've been looking at a lot of OOTB components and I thought I was getting somewhere with it however I really lack knowledge on ATG, as I'm a placement student who's only really been looking at it properly for 1/2 months.

My current thought is to hook my custom code into the **performScheduledTask** by extending **SingletonSchedulableService** however all the current scheduled tasks are extending the **SingletonSchedulableService** and It doesn't sound like a good idea to go into every one (30+) java files and change them? I'm really not sure about that.

The following code is a rough idea of what I would want to happen using the pre-existing **performScheduledTask** adding my own code into it. When **doScheduledTask** is called I send a messaging saying it's starting and when it finishes see whether there was an error or not and send a suitable message.

```
public void performScheduledTask(Scheduler scheduler, ScheduledJob job) {
    boolean gotLock = false;

    try {
        gotLock = acquireLock();

        if (gotLock) {
            if (isLoggingDebug())

            try {
                startTime= getJobTime();
                sendToStart(name, description, id, startTime);
                doScheduledTask(scheduler, job);

            } catch (Exception e){ 
                errorMsg= e.getMessage();
            }

            if (mErrorMessage == null) {
                endTime= getJobTime();
                String msg= "This job completed successfully";
                sendToSuccess(name, description, id, endTime, msg);
            } else {
                endtime = getJobTime();
                sendToFail(name, description, id, endtime, msg);
            }

        } else if (isLoggingDebug())
            logDebug("sleeping until next scheduled wakeup.");

    } finally {
        if (gotLock) 
            releaseLock();
    }

}
```

I'm a bit lost at the moment as I've never done a web app completely by myself, let alone hooking it into these scheduled Jobs so any help would be very much appreciated. If you need any extra information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So have you considered using `dyn/admin` for this purpose?  There is a page which can be accessed `http://<your-host-name:<port>/dyn/admin/nucleus/atg/dynamo/service/Scheduler` which has a lot of the information you are looking for.

Also, scheduled components have the Performance Monitor built in which implement the methods `startOperation` and `endOperation`.  Would recommend you look at using these instead of hooking your code into the `performScheduledTask()` method.  The performance monitor can be enabled/disabled for a property on the scheduled component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The scheduler in dyn/admin is how it is currently looked at, however this does not give any indication of whether the job failed or if it ran successfully, which is what my web application will (hopefully) solve.

I will definitely look into the start operation and end operation, I had looked at it previously but didn't think it was correct so I'll go back to it.
Thanks again for getting back to me.

Comment: Understood.  I would recommend you consider implementing something like JMX/SNMP within your scheduled components then.  This would mean that you would not create the interface within ATG but rather configure whatever tool your company uses for monitoring.

Comment: Hi, do you mean adding in functionality to each job? We don't currently have anything monitoring the scheduled jobs - we just find out about a week later that something has failed and we don't know when!

Comment: ps sorry if my questions are stupid, I'm a placement student out of her depth!! hah

Comment: @RebeccaWilde the short answer is yes, insert functionality in each "job" or scheduled component (ATG terminology).  If you implement JMX/SNMP this monitoring software will be able to listen for the SNMP broadcasts (check with someone in the operations team first!). This would probably involve creating a new ATG component (java class + property file = component) which implements the JMX/SNMP functionality.  You would then change the respective scheduled components to use your new SNMP broadcaster to send scheduled event info.  I would recommend you discuss this with an architect. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Most Oracle Commerce sites will use some form of log monitoring to monitor and alert to issues, including Scheduled services. Splunk is a popular tool.

It can be a bit of an iterative process in identifying the errors that are important to site and setting up actions for them.

If you want to stay within the ATG framework, you could extend the logging system, creating a new LogEvent sink that listens for messages from a particular Originator and then performs some action, like sending an email.

Here is the documention on the logging framework.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGPlatformProgGuide/html/s1102logevents01.html

Another approach would be to extend each of the scheduled service classes and set the $class attribute of the service to your new class.  This way you can "intercept" the calls to performScheduledTask and add your logic, catch exceptions etc.

```
performScheduledTask(..){

  try{
    super.performScheduledTask()
  }catch(SomeException ex){
     //Do something with it
  }

}
```

This way you aren't changing any code in the per existing classes, and you can just pick an choose which services you are "monitoring"